# Downloading Image from server using universal image loader

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

In my app I'm downloading Images from server and setting images into view pager.Everything works fine but there is a slight delay(say 8-10 sec on Wifi) in downloading image. The image size ranges from 200kb-800kb. and I have also added a progress bar while downloading is in progress but the progress bar does not shows up.
Can somebody help me on this.
Below is the code.

```
public void fetchImageUrl() {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    String url = URLMap.getUploadImgChangeStatus("get_amazonserver_image");
    url = url.replace("{id}", companyId).replace("{crid}", callRecordId);
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            System.out.println("Response0000" + response);
            if (response.equals("[]")) {
                setView();
            } else {
                getAmazonImageUrl(response);
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.i("ErrorListner=", error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(request);
}

public void getAmazonImageUrl(String response) {
    try {
        imgUrl = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] arr;
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            if (jArray.getJSONObject(i).has("ImagePath")) {
                arr = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("ImagePath").split("\\s+");
                imgUrl = Arrays.asList(arr);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    }
    imageViewAdapter = new ImageViewAdapter(this, iv, imgUrl, viewPager, this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(imageViewAdapter);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Below is my adapter class

```
public class ImageViewAdapter extends android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter {
private Context context;
ImageView imageView;
ProgressBar progressBar;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
ViewPager viewPager;
Activity activity;
List<String> imgUrl;

public ImageViewAdapter(Context context, ImageView imageView, List<String> imgUrl,
                        ViewPager viewPager, Activity activity){
    System.out.println("Inside ImageViewAdapter");
    this.context=context;
    this.imageView = imageView;
    this.viewPager = viewPager;
    this.activity = activity;
    this.imgUrl=imgUrl;
    System.out.println(imgUrl.size());
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return imgUrl.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
}


@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_swipe_custom_layout, container, false);
    //setting custom font
    Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/DroidSerif.ttf");
    TextView tv = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_count);
    tv.setTypeface(custom_font);
    imageView = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    progressBar=(ProgressBar)item_view.findViewById(R.id.imgLoadingPbar);

    // UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER SETUP
    DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheOnDisc(true).cacheInMemory(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
            .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            context)
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
            .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
            .discCacheSize(100 * 1024 * 1024).build();

    com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);


    // UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER OPTION SETUP
    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true).resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_user)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.noimgavailable)
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.spinner_border).build();

    /*final Animation animation= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.rotate);*/

    com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader imageLoader = com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.displayImage(imgUrl.get(position), imageView, options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
            progressBar.setProgress(0);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {

        }
    });

    if(position == 0) {
        tv.setText("Image " + "1");
        tv.setTypeface(custom_font);
    }else if(position == 1) {
        tv.setText("Image " + "2");
        tv.setTypeface(custom_font);
    } else if(position == 2) {
        tv.setText("Image " + "3");
        tv.setTypeface(custom_font);
    }
    container.addView(item_view);
    return item_view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    //((ViewPager)container).removeView((View)object);
    container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
}
```

}

I have tried using picasso, Async task but everything is same.. Picasso and universal image loader almost takes same time but async task is even more late.
The progress bar which is set in activity class shows up for a second or two second. but when it goes to adapter class I have another progress bar which does not shows up.
My problems are
 1. Is there any way where I can download images faster
 2. and how make use of progress bar properly.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can add the Progress Bar in specific position.Sample code are belowe. If there is any problem follow this link [Universal Image Loader description](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

```
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView, options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
@Override
public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
    ...
}
@Override
public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
    ...
}
@Override
public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
    ...
}
@Override
public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
    ...
}
```

}, new ImageLoadingProgressListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(String imageUri, View view, int current, int total) {
        ...
    }
});

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got the solution. along with progress bar we need to set view as well.
I'm posting code.

```
com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader imageLoader = com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.displayImage(imgUrl.get(position), imageView, options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
            //progressBar.setProgress(0);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you got it to download faster?